# Compressing Image using AsyncTask before uploading to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-storage

I'm trying to compress images before uploading them to Firebase Storage using this class that extends AsyncTask

```
public class BackgroundImageResize extends AsyncTask<Uri, Integer, byte[]> {

    Bitmap mBitmap;

    public BackgroundImageResize(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap != null){
            this.mBitmap = bitmap;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this, "compressing image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       // showProgressBar();
    }

    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(Uri... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: started.");

        if(mBitmap == null){
            try{
                mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(NextActivity.this.getContentResolver(), params[0]);
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        byte[] bytes = null;
        bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(mBitmap, 100);
        return bytes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
        super.onPostExecute(bytes);
        mUploadBytes = bytes;
     //   hideProgressBar();
        //execute the upload task

    }
}

public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality,stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

using this onClickView to call it

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to the final share screen.");

            //Compress the image

           try{ backgroundImageResize.execute() ; } catch (NullPointerException e) {}


            //upload the image to firebase
            Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this, "Attempting to upload new photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String caption = mCaption.getText().toString();

            if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image))){
                imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image));
                mFirebaseMethods.uploadNewPhoto(getString(R.string.new_photo), caption, imageCount, imgUrl,null);
            }
            else if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_bitmap))){
                bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra(getString(R.string.selected_bitmap));
                mFirebaseMethods.uploadNewPhoto(getString(R.string.new_photo), caption, imageCount, null,bitmap);
            }
```

**My question is, how do I pass the bitmap or url to this BackgroundImageResize at onCLickListener ?**

this is the firebase storage upload method

```
 public void uploadNewPhoto(String photoType, final String caption,final int count, final String imgUrl,
                           Bitmap bm){
    Log.d(TAG, "uploadNewPhoto: attempting to uplaod new photo.");

    FilePaths filePaths = new FilePaths();
    //case1) new photo
    if(photoType.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.new_photo))){
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadNewPhoto: uploading NEW photo.");

        String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        StorageReference storageReference = mStorageReference
                .child(filePaths.FIREBASE_IMAGE_STORAGE + "/" + user_id + "/photo" + (count + 1));

        //convert image url to bitmap
        if(bm == null){
            bm = ImageManager.getBitmap(imgUrl);
        }

        byte[] bytes = ImageManager.getBytesFromBitmap(bm, 90);


        UploadTask uploadTask = null;
        uploadTask = storageReference.putBytes(bytes);

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri firebaseUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "photo upload success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //add the new photo to 'photos' node and 'user_photos' node
                addPhotoToDatabase(caption, firebaseUrl.toString());

                //navigate to the main feed so the user can see their photo
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Photo upload failed.");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Photo upload failed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

                if(progress - 15 > mPhotoUploadProgress){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "photo upload progress: " + String.format("%.0f", progress) + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mPhotoUploadProgress = progress;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "onProgress: upload progress: " + progress + "% done");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your `BackgroundImageResize` class you can pass the bitmap itself to the constructor. I cannot find the place where you create your your instance of `BackgroundImageResize` but you should do it like this:

```
BackgroundImageResize backgroundImageResize = new BackgroundImageResize(bitmap);
```

You also can pass the Uri to the `execute()` method in `onClick()` like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    ...
    try{ backgroundImageResize.execute(yourUri); } catch (NullPointerException e) {}
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your welcome. Feel free to accept the answer, if it works for you ;)